# Pushing interdependent Cocoapods to Repo CDN - issue with eventual consistency

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, cocoapods

Interested if someone knows of a way to effectively push interdependent pods to the CocoaPods Trunk since the Repo CDN update.

Let's say I have 2 pods in a monorepo: **pod1** and **pod2** where **pod1** is listed as a dependency for **pod2**.

A script in my CI pipeline increments the versions of the pods and dependencies in the respective spec files.

pod1.podspec:

```
...
s.version = 1.0.1
```

pod2.podspec:

```
...
s.version = 1.4.4
s.dependency 'pod1', '1.0.1'
```

The script then pushes the pods to Trunk one after the other:

1. `pod push pod1.podspec` pushes to Trunk successfully under the new version (1.0.1)
2. `pod push pod2.podspec` - fails validation and errors out with e.g.

```
-> pod2 (1.4.4)
- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "pod1":
In Podfile:
    pod2 was resolved to 1.4.4, which depends on
      pod1 (= 1.0.1)
```

If I wait 5 mins and then run `pod push pod2.podspec` again, it succeeds.

It would appear that objects in the Repo CDN have a TTL of ~ 5 mins.

It would be possible to have the deploy script wait 5 minutes after each pod push but that is suboptimal, especially for monorepos with many interdependent pods. I've thought about loosening the version requirement, e.g. `s.dependency 'pod1', '~> 1.0.1'` but that's not always a viable option either.

I've not been able to find much information about this, so I wanted to see if anyone has arrived at better solutions to this problem.

Comment: PR in progress at https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-trunk/pull/147

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `pod repo update` after `pod push pod1.podspec`.